# Declarative (Annotation-based) Caching Solution for Java

Tags: java, caching, annotations, ehcache, declarative

Besides [Spring 3.1](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/09/spring-framework-3-1-m2-released/) and [ehcache-spring-annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/), do we have other alternatives that are other than EhCache and Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Spring-AOP based solutions? You can create an auto-proxy object in your Spring applicationContext using the **org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor** and then make an object that implements **AfterReturningAdvice, ThrowsAdvice** and **MethodBeforeAdvice**.

Use that object to monitor function calls and exits and cache what information you want.

```
<bean name="cacheHandler" class="org.yourname.CachingInterceptor" />
<bean id="cacheAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
  <property name="advice" ref="cacheHandler" />
  <property name="pattern" value="org.yourname.regex.of.stuff.you.want.cached.*" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" />
```